Existence of the limit of a function around the origin
Let $F:[0,\infty)\mapsto[0,\infty)$ be an increasing and convex function that is equal to zero at the origin.
That is, the function $F$ satisfies: $F(0)=0$, $F'(x)>0$ (strict), and $F''(x)\geq 0$ (non-strict).
Does the following limit always exist?
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xF'(x)}{F(x)}
\end{align}
Note that the convexity of $F$ ensures that $\frac{xF'(x)}{F(x}\geq 1$.

By the assumption that $F^{\prime}$ is strictly positive, it follows from L'Hopital's rule that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xF'(x)}{F(x)}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{xF^{\prime\prime}(x)+F^{\prime}(x)}{F^{\prime}(x)}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F^{\prime}(x)}{F^{\prime}(x)}=1.
\end{equation}
